# Android Studio Call Activity From Custom Class

Tags: java, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity, android-context

My problem is that the **openWA** method does not work if it is created inside **GlobalFunc class** (just like my code below). But it's working if i try to create the method inside **MainActivity class**.
I want that it should work when it is created inside the GlobalFunc class.

May I know my mistake ?

The GlobalFunc class :-

```
public class GlobalFunc{


public void openWA(Context c, String n){

        try {

            String toNumber = n;

            Intent wa = new Intent();

            wa.putExtra("jid", toNumber + "@s.whatsapp.net");

            wa.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hola...");

            wa.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            wa.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

            wa.setType("text/plain");

            c.startActivity(wa);

        }

        catch (Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}
```

```
MainActivity:-


import com.myapp.mobile.GlobalFunc;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private Button sendWA;

GlobalFunc GF = new GlobalFunc();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

sendWA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnWA);

sendWA.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override

public void onClick(View v) {

if(v==sendWA){

GF.openWA(getApplicationContext(),"62xxxxx");

}

}

}
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Please properly format your code before posting.

Comment: Please include the log details